# Symbian programming on Windows with C++ - how to guide

Tags: c++, qt

I need to program for Symbian and it is likely that I will use Qt by devc++. What tools should I download to be effective and can you point me towards good 'getting started' tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

For a basic start you would need [Nokia Qt SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html) and a good wiki like [Qt for Symbian](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Category%3aQt_for_Symbian)

The Nokia Qt SDK includes the qt framework sdk, the nokia sdk and a Symbian Emulator.
The Wiki is full of info to get you busy for a while. If you can't decide where to start
[this wiki page](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Using_Qt_Creator_With_Symbian) is a good one.